# Downloading data from Firebase WHERE name = "someString"

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Firebase, and trying to query a Firebase database.

I have a firebase tree which looks like that:

```
"mainData": 
   "users":
      "user1ID" :
         "name" : "John Mccgee"
         "age" : 54
         "hobbies" : 
            1 : "Playing Piano"
            2 : "Programming"
            3 : "Going to parties"
            4 : "Hiking"

       "user2ID" :
         "name" : "Jack Jones"
         "age" : 22
         "hobbies" : 
            1 : "Playing Soccer"
            2 : "Programming"
            3 : "Telling Jokes"

       "user3ID" :
          ...
```

I want to search inside my database where `"name"`, for example, starts with "Jac", and download it's **`"hobbies"` only**... I know I can search by name, but when I do, Firebase downloads all the childs under `"user2ID"`.

So, is it possible to download only the childs which are under `"hobbies"`, when searching by other child?     (`"name"`)

Thank you for reading, and answering of course. I hope the question is clear enough (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Firebase client for iOS always downloads entire nodes directly under the level where you execute the query (or otherwise attach the listener). This is one of the many, many reasons why experienced Firebasers (and the documentation) recommend against mixing entity types in the tree.

In your current model there is no way to read or query the user names, without also reading the hobbies of all users. To prevent this, split the hobbies from the other user data:

```
"users":
  "user1ID" :
     "name" : "John Mccgee"
     "age" : 54

   "user2ID" :
     "name" : "Jack Jones"
     "age" : 22

   "user3ID" :
      ...

"hobbies":
  "user1ID" :
        1 : "Playing Piano"
        2 : "Programming"
        3 : "Going to parties"
        4 : "Hiking"

   "user2ID" :
        1 : "Playing Soccer"
        2 : "Programming"
        3 : "Telling Jokes"

   "user3ID" :
      ...
```

You will still have to execute to read operations against the database:

1. find the UID for the user given their name
2. find the hobbies for the user given their UID

Comment: but the two read operations will still be too separate calls to the db. Isn't there a way to make just one call and get the required result? Please enlighten me.

Comment: Your current data model allows you to do that. But it retrieves more data than you want, and goes against recommendations from Firebase documentation and experts.